My code is working without "headless" option but it doesnt work on "headless"
This is my code it works without headless, the website gives makes the request as expected but in headless mode it doesnt make the expected request. It can be about the website that im trying to log requests but i dont know how to bypass it or something
import { Options, WebDriver, until, Builder, By } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import chrome from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';
import CDP from 'chrome-remote-interface';
import { download } from './download';

interface Response {
    url: string;
}

interface ResponseReceivedParams {
    response: Response;
}

const options = new chrome.Options();
//options.addArguments('--headless=new')
options.addArguments('--no-sandbox');
options.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage');
options.addArguments('--remote-debugging-port=9224'); // Remote debugging port
options.addArguments('--window-size=1920x1080');
options.addArguments('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled');
//options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")

const driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();

export async function getAlucard(url: string, selectedFansub: string) {
    let responseReceived = false; // Flag to track if the desired response has been received
    const client = await CDP({ port: 9224 });
    const { Network } = client;

    try {
        await Network.enable();

        Network.responseReceived(({ response }: ResponseReceivedParams) => {
            console.log('Response URL:', response.url);
            if (!responseReceived && response.url.includes('https://alucard.stream/cdn/playlist/')) {
                console.log('Bulunan URL:', response.url);
                responseReceived = true;
                download(response.url);
            }
        });

        await driver.get(url);

        const specificElementSelector = '.btn-group.pull-right';
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(specificElementSelector)), 10000);

        const ajax = 'https://www.turkanime.co/' + selectedFansub;
        const script = 
            `IndexIcerik('${ajax}','videodetay');`
        ;

        await driver.executeScript(script);

        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            if (!responseReceived) {
                console.warn('Timeout: Closing driver.');
                responseReceived = true; // Mark to avoid calling quit again
                client.close();
                driver.close();
                driver.quit();
            }
        }, 10000); // Adjust timeout duration as needed

        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            const checkResponseInterval = setInterval(() => {
                if (responseReceived) {
                    clearInterval(checkResponseInterval);
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    resolve(null);
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Hata:', error);
    } finally {
        await client.close(); // Close the CDP client
        await driver.close();
        await driver.quit(); // Ensure driver quits on completion or error
    }
}

Tried with headless, headless=new
It resulted headless gives some policy errors:
[0804/134121.329:INFO:CONSOLE(110)] "Permissions policy violation: accelerometer is not allowed in this document.", source: https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingCachedScripts//Ad_2_263_3_0/ebHtml5Banner.js (110)
....

headless=new doesnt give any error.

The --headless option is deprecated since Selenium 4.8.0 (see link), it is recommended to only use --headless=new, so you should not be worried about the Permissions policy violation that is raised by --headless mode.
That being said, what is wrong about the --headles=new mode? What is the output you get and what were you expecting?

@Denel I expect a link that includes "alucard.stream" in the network responses it works everytime in normal but in the headless it doesnt give a single "alucard.stream" response
Example url:
https://www.turkanime.co/video/kinnikuman-kanpeki-ch-ujin-shiso-hen-0-bolum
(it doesnt include "fansub" which effects the requests so you can be able to look at responses easily, if the website is not reachable try with vpn its blocked on some countries)

I've tried looking into it, but it seems that running in headless does not load the video stream and thus does not give you the URL you are looking for. When running your code I inspected the loaded webpage of the headless program using chrome://inspect and selecting the webpage. It showed a "404 not found" in place of the video stream instead of the video stream itself. I would not know how to circumvent this.
